# Создать Textview в виде флага в android

Tags: android, xml, android-customview

Доброго времени суток! Возник такой вопрос. Как в Android сделать вот такую штуку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть текстбокс с фоном в виде вот такого флажка. 
Проблема еще и в том что я даже не знаю как это правильно называется - по запросу Android flag поисковик думает что мне нужно что-то связанное с булевскими переменными. 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: вам всего лишь надо установить фон для `TextView` в виде вашего *флага*

Comment: @metalurgus а с таким решением не будет проблем масштабирования на разных экранах?

Comment: Вам нужно использовать .9.png

Answer (score 1):

Надо создать `drawable` в виде `shape`, типа (в данном случае прямоугольник с закругленными краями):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="15dp">
 <solid android:color="#bbbbbb"/>
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
  android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
  android:topRightRadius="30p"/>
</shape>
```

Далее сослаться на этот `shape` как:

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/my_shape" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Теперь вам надо нарисовать средствами `shape` ваш флажок. Возможно shape не поможет, тогда останется только `nine-patch`.

[Документация здесь](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Comment: А зачем нужны скругленные края? Просто для самого флажка они не обязательны

Comment: это был пример, если вы нечаянно подумали, что вам кто-то здесь нарисует флажок - то вы глубоко ошиблись ))